# Different border color according to different li

Tags: css

I am trying to make a post system in which I want different `right border color` for each post. But I want to use a maximum of 4 colors.The first four posts will have four different colors, and then again the next four posts will have the colors of the first four posts (different again for each four posts). I know how to do it via odd and even nth element in css. For example I tried:

```
li:nth-child(odd) {
  border-left:1px solid #ff0000;
}
li:nth-child(even) {
  border-left:1px solid #0000ff;
}
```

How to do it the way I want: the first four a different color, and then again the next four with the same colors, and again for the next four?

Comment: You should do it server-side. What are you using for server-side scripting?

Comment: it can be done via css . i am using simple css to do it .

Comment: May be you could try around the `:nth-child(Xn +- Y)` formula so you could ensure the 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th, also they should be declared in that way so the "special" ones (3rd and 4rd) can override 1st and 2nd.

Comment: @GurpreetSingh ok it its possible with js/jquery i dnt have any problem

Comment: @banzsh exactly i am trying to use that but colors are coming in incorrect order can you help me out ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use these:

```
li:nth-child(4n+1) { /* Every first */
  border-left:1px solid #ff0000;
}
li:nth-child(4n+2) { /* Every second */
  border-left:1px solid #0000ff;
}
li:nth-child(4n+3) { /* Every third */
  ...
}
li:nth-child(4n+4) {/* Every fourth */
  ...
}
```

Comment: @Param Veer if you need to do testing with nth-child again, you could try this. http://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/

Comment: It be worth noting that this pseudo class isn't suppoted in IE8 and below.
So, if cross browser compatibility is important to you you could use jQuery with the same code above to apply a class to the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, and 4th and then specify the styles in those classes.

Comment: @DigitalBiscuits thanks for telling me that . i am giving support for ie9 . though ill make a jquery version soon :)